# What is a good and affordable 27" 1080p and 144 Hz monitor that the given specs?

Tags: monitors

**Computer Specs**

Monitor: LG 23" WX235V

Processor: Intel i3-9100F

GPU: Radeon RX570

Ram: 16gb

Storage: Samsung EVO 970 500gb M.2 Nvme

I am mainly going to play Player unknown's battleground (PUBG) and currently I have a monitor by LG and I feel the colors are bad and only has a 59Hz refresh rate with a 23" display that caps at 1080p. I am not sure but I would say the sweet spot is a 27" monitor.

I am eye-ing a 144Hz monitor with a IPS panel and preferably supports 1440p. But I am not sure if my current specs can even handle games at a larger resolution and higher refresh rate so it is also nice to get feedback on this aspect given my GPU is a mid range one.

There are some brands like HKC where I see locally that are very cheap but I always question these kinds of really affordable brands even when specs are good.

I am hopefully eyeing a monitor in the price budget of ideally $200 with a maximum of $250

If the budget is too low perhaps a 1080p monitor with 27" size and 144 Hz?

Comment: While high refresh rate monitors still have some benefit even if the FPS can't keep up, I think you would be better off with a 1080p monitor. The RX 570 is not nearly powerful enough for 1440p at high FPS, and the 200$ budget seems better suited for a 1080p monitor. Especially if you want 144Hz and IPS.

Comment: @MechEng I suppose 1080p is the way to go. Do you have suggestions on any reliable brands/models that have a 27" 1080p with 144 Hz and and IPS panel?

Comment: Sorry, I am not in the loop as far as gaming monitors are concerned. But If you edit your question to reflect the new goal, then maybe someone else has a good recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

The monitor I use mostly fits your description:
The AOC C27G1.
It's a very nice VA panel and supports DDC-CI and FreeSync. There's also the CQ27G1, which is 1440p at 27", rather than the C27G1's 1080p.

Whether your system will be sufficient to achieve decent framerates mostly depends on the games you'll play and what settings you want to play them at.

Comment: Thanks, I just checked on this now. Although based on a review, the true refresh rate of this monitor should be only about 100hz instead of 144hz given the high response time. Also the white balance is said to be off (which can be fixed mostly with tweaking the settings).

Comment: The 1440p version has an extra Q in its name: https://us.aoc.com/en/gaming-monitors/cq27g1
I'm not sure I'd recommend it anymore though - mine has started the flicker quite a bit when using FreeSync.

Comment: That's sad to hear it's real cheap though about half the price of most 27" 1440p monitors. I'm considering getting LG `27GL850-B 27 Inch Ultragear QHD Nano IPS` instead. Only cons so far that is quite significant is the contrast ratio and the brightness which is only at 350 nits. But then again my GPU isn't too strong